# To delete() or forceDelete(). A better way to determine

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with 95 tables. A `users` tables exists for the system users. Many other tables (45 out of the 95) have a "created_by" that refers to the user who created/added the row, through `users.id`.

Now. If I wanted to delete a user, I just cannot go and do `$user->delete()`, I need to keep the user around (soft-delete it) in case this user has created rows on other tables. But what if this user didn't add any content, then I should just go ahead and `$user->forceDelete()` it.

My question is: is there a good way to go about doing this? To check whether a user should be deleted or Force-deleted when we have this big number of tables.

I figured I could just loop though the tables and check if the id of the user (to be deleted) exists, if found then it's ->delete(), else it's ->forceDelete(). Here is the code:

```php
            // Get all tables
            $allTables = \DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
            $tablesWithCreatedBy = [];
            foreach($allTables as $tableName){
                $tableColumns = \DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($tableName);

                if(in_array('created_by', $tableColumns)){
                    $tablesWithCreatedBy[] = $tableName;
                }
            }

            foreach($tablesWithCreatedBy as $tableName){
                $result = \DB::select(" SELECT created_by FROM `$tableName`
                    WHERE `created_by` = {$this->user->id} LIMIT 0, 1 ");

                if(isset($result[0])){
                    $this->user->delete();
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If wasn't trashed from the code above, then force delete the user!
            if(!$this->user->trashed()){
                $this->user->forceDelete();
            }
```

I feel there must be a better way to do it! Is there?

Comment: I would just don't force delete any of them. Because this way will make you come back and change this code everytime a new soft deleted user is required in a query for your future features. In the future, when you really need this tiny space in your database; you can write a code for the state that day and optimize your database as you like.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN I am not sure I understand what you mean. And yes, I could just NOT forceDelete() any user, but what happens when a new user is being added with username that is taken by a deleted user?! You just cannot duplicate the username, and also cannot change the delete user's, because he/she might be restored!

Comment: it looks like I misunderstand your question, my bad. It felt like your question is an imaginary problem and that is why I wrote I would not try to handle it programmatically on every delete request from the development point. But rather trigger optimization logic manually when required, or use an `event handler`, `GC`, `history table` or `cronjob` solution when the problem really occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You've to add `records_count` to `users` table that will be incremented every time when user adds content to other tables, so after that change solution will be simple as:

```
$result = ($this->user->records_count > 0) 
          ? $this->user->delete() 
          : $this->user->forceDelete();
```

Or write Laravel Console Command and run it at background that will walk through db and do cleanup operations.

Comment: Sure, thought about that. But we are talking about 45 tables! That's 45 of `where id IN ( SELECT created_by FROM X) OR ...` in one query! I think my code would be much more performant because it stops on the first found result, which I know could be the 45th, but it could also be the first!

Comment: @Dewan159 think about: 45 network packets (queries) between app and db or 2 simple queries and let db do it's job. Just add index to `created_by` - and You'll see how fast it will do it. p.s. indexes does that `if checks` for You.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I am not sure. But I am trying to find an elegant way to do it, with respect to the number of the tables. But thanks

Comment: @Dewan159 I think You've to simplify architecture by adding `records_count` to users table that will be incremented every time when user adds content to other tables. So after just simply act by state of that field

Comment: Great idea, with Laravel's model events it should be simple enough to implement this. But we have a standing system already, this would only work as you know for a system that has not been used yet, since "records_count" will be zero, but the users would still actually own data!

Comment: @Dewan159 so what's problem to write migration file to add that field and call fixture or seeder that will calculate records for current users and set `records_count`?